# PC reboots when user logs in AFTER connecting with remote desktop

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

When a user connects to a PC on the domain via remote desktop, it will reboot when they then log in locally.

They can log in repeatedly remotely with no issues.
But as soon as he is back in front of it, log in - reboot.

I cant see any errors in the event viewer (assuming thats where they would be) and its only this 1 pc over the network of hundreds.

Any ideas whats up?

XP, sp3 (or maybe 2, i forget).

Comment: You said you don't see errors in the Event Log, but what events are showing around the actual Shutdown event?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you're experiencing on this machine is actually a reboot.  It sounds more like this user is not logging out properly when he's done using the workstation (remotely or locally).  If they don't actually **logout**, the session stays active and is resumable *if* the user connects in the same way they created the suspended session (i.e. Local->Local or Remote->Remote).  If you move from one to the other (Local->Remote or Remote->Local) with a suspended session in progress, it will automatically log that session out when the user logs in and start a new one.